# Stuck with IEEE-754 format (binary to decimal conversion)

Tags: arithmetic, number-systems

I am stuck with a problem,
[image]

Now here is the formula applied to a question,
[image]

The red colored bits show the exponent(e) while, the yellow bits are fraction (f). Now I am confused with how did the author convert the fraction (f) into 1-2^(-23). I understand that he has converted from binary to decimal to get this value but how do I convert such a big number from binary to decimal?

**EDIT:**

One trick that my teacher told me was to convert from binary to hexadecimal and then convert the value to decimal easily. But doing that has given me a value `8388607` which is not equal to `1 - 2 ^(-23)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion from $23$ bits, all $1$ to $1-2^{23}$ comes from the fact that summing $\sum_{i=1}^{23}2^{-i}=1-2^{-23}$.  The final conversion is from $-2^{128}$ (the $2^{104}$ is negligible) to $-3.4E38$, which is done using the base $10$ logarithm of $2$.  $\log_{10}2^{128}=128\log_{10}2\approx 128\cdot.30103\approx 38.532$, so $2^{128} \approx 3.4E38$